# Can't find remesh button

Tags: interface, sculpting, sculpt

I'm pretty a newbie here and also in Blender in general.

I'm in trouble with one thing in particular:

How could I switch sculpting through different objects in sculpt mode? Let me first say that I use a tablet with pen so I have enabled *Emulate 3 Button Mouse*. I know that I have to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and click on an object but if I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> on the object I want to switch it doesn't receive the input, also if I have flagged

[image]

What can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the main question, remesh can be found in 2 places when in sculpt mode. One is in the header of the 3D View to the right, maybe you need to scroll it with the "alt+click" on your pen or middle mouse button, the second one is in the Active Tools and Workspace Settings, right above the Render Properties tab, there between Options and Workspace. [image: Pointing out where the Remesh function can be found]

Regarding the switching of objects while in sculpt mode, since you are using the middle mouse button emulation, the alt is not working since it's used for rotating the 3D View.
You may have to use "ctrl-tab" to open a pie menu and select "object-mode", to switch back, well same pie-menu. Sadly the one keymap that could make it easier is non-modal, means it would overwrite not only the mode change in sculpting, but also in the object-mode. If you primary use sculpting it may be interesting for you non the less. In the second picture, the marked "Edit Mode" can be changed to "Object Mode", but as i mentioned it will toggle not only in sculpt mode, but also in other modes. You can always reset it back to "Edit Mode" though. It seems that you may need to switch at least once manually back to sculpt mode if you add a new object after switching from sculpt mode and select the new object, from then on it usually works fine with just "tab" to change mode, change selection and "tab" back, happy sculpting.
[image: Blender Preferences - Object Non-modal keymap]

Comment: The possibility to set your own key mappings is well used, especially by people that work a lot with certain functions. They may use it like their bread and butter and thus not mention it in their videos. Some functions can be set for convenience, others are more like a choice, as they affect more then one area but can be time saving, if you most the time use Blender for a specific task, like sculpting. There is also the possibility of addons being used, some tutorials mention them others don't (and there are a lot addons available).

Comment: OK Xylvier thanks for the switch mode issue. But i'm still confused for the REMESH issue. The Remesh button i ment is at the minute 20:43 :      https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oXNZIIDZC48&list=PLYbYi6Db2_VBIQ71YOZ4JZtY1oENZ-qaD&index=10&t=0s                                                                                                       is the same?

Comment: I just watched the video and indeed there is that nice feature, BUT consider that he is not using the emulation of the middle mouse button at that time, if you pause at the time he uses "Alt"+LMB, you see that the info left hand bottom says "Select" for the currently pressed key combination. His solution works and i may try to find a way around the middle mouse emulation to profit from this ease of use, but if you have the emulation on, it sadly does not work that easy. That said, the video you linked is 1:02 long? It's one of many in a playlist, maybe you can point out which video it was.

Comment: Thanks Xylvier. In the comment below i have indicated witch part of te video. At the minute 20:43 he show the remesh function that i can't find. I don't think is the same that you showed to me. Is it?

Comment: @matibuc I checked all videos that where in that playlist and some mentioned remesh, while only the 1 hour+ one mentioned it at around the time you pointed out. The one he mentioned there is essentially the one i pointed out as well in the first picture with the red arrow and number 1.

Comment: Yes right it looks the same you pointed in the first picture at N1. But i don't know why i don't have in my interface. You know why?

Comment: While it could be that you had an older version, i believe even the 2.8 should have had that feature. Other then that, it could be the resolution and limited space in the top of your 3D-view hiding it. There you can use the middle mouse button to scroll and look for the function. Was i believe even shown in the video, where he scrolled the header of the 3D view and opened the remesh menu.

Comment: Ok Xylvier. Find the prob. I had an older version: 2.8  and there was nothing there. I installed the new 2.81 and i have everythingg now. Thanks a lot for the help. I'm very gratefull.